# how to store some styles in one css variable?

Tags: html, css

I am new at web, I am working on a side project just building a simple website, so my question is next: how can I store some styles in one variable for example:

```
font-family: acumin-pro, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;
```

I know how to store one style in variable, like this:

```
:root{
   --main_font: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

so, can you give me some examples or advises about that?

Comment: *how can I store some styles in one variable for example:* --> this is what classes are made for, they contain a set of styles and you use the class when you want to apply them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to do this with CSS and the variables are only for values. However, if you are able to use SASS in your website then you would be able to use mixins which are a set of defined styles that can be reused throughout your stylesheet.

You can read more about SASS and mixins [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin)

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking same, but I decided to go with only CSS for now.